# Why are mean and standard deviation not exactly as I entered on R?

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics, histogram

We're looking at a random sample of the heights of 100 males at our school. These are our instructions:

 Click on Distributions -> Continuous distributions -> Normal distribution -> Sample from normal distribution

 Mean: 175
 Standard deviation: 7
 Number of samples (rows): 100
 Number of observations (columns): 1
 Under Add to Data Set uncheck Sample means.
 Click OK. This will store a new data set called NormalSamples. It should automatically become the active data set. Click View data set and you will see a single column of values (1 sample) with 100 rows (individuals in the sample). You may now perform commands on this sample of values as with any other data set.

I then had to construct a histogram based on this data and then generate a descriptive statistics output, and this is what I got for my output:

```
 mean       sd      IQR         cv  skewness  kurtosis       0%      25%
```

175.4242 6.820305 8.431871 0.03887893 0.3557489 0.5100971 158.4122 171.1073
      50%      75%     100%   n
 175.1562 179.5392 196.9389 100

The question is, why are the mean and the standard deviation not exactly equal to 175 and 7, respectively? Is it because it's a random sample, and it wouldn't be truly random if they were exact?

Comment: Yes.  This exercise is no doubt intended to introduce you to randomness and its effects on our ability to know what's "real", in this case, what the true mean and standard deviation of height are.

Comment: Rather than posting this question, it would take you far less time, and perhaps be more instructive, to repeat your mouseclicks and see what (if anything) changes between one random sample and another.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are *random* draws from the distribution. The statistics you calculated are properties of the sample, while the initial settings are properties of the underlying distribution, "population" if you prefer such terminology. The true mean would be the mean over the infinite possible values from the distribution. The empirical mean is the mean of the sample that you've drawn. By the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), the empirical mean converges to the true expected value, but this doesn't mean that with small, finite sample you can expect them to be the same. You can expect that as your sample grows, they should get closer unless your sampling is not random, or your are dealing with one of the pathological cases like [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).